# LiPo Battery power monitoring with ESP-12E

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, analog, voltage-divider, esp8266

I am using 3.7V LiPo battery and ESP-12E in this project. I need to monitor how much charge is there in the battery to help when battery falls below certain level and notify to charge it up again. I've red that 3.7 LiPo batteries maximum voltage goes upto 4.2V. And readable analog input voltage for ESP-12E is 0-1V.
I was planning to make a simple voltage divider to convert 4.2V to 1V and provide it to analog input of ESP-12E.
Voltage divider resistors -
Input Voltage:4.2V
Output Voltage:1V
R1: 1 Kohm
R2: 330 ohm

So as charge in the battery drops the analog input voltage to the ESP-12E drops. But I have a doubt about voltage divider wether to use voltage divider or something else for this project. Because voltage divider will consume power continuously to drain the battery and will cause the circuit inefficient. and I've also red that voltage divider is mostly used in high impedance circuits.

So is simple voltage divider suitable for this circuit or should I use some other DC-DC converter or regulator for converting 4.2V to 1V more efficiently to drain as much less possible power from battery itself to provide it to analog Input of ESP-12E?

Comment: What is the mAh capacity of your Lipo?

Comment: why don't u use higher values for resistors, like 10K & 3.3K. You could also use precision resistor with tolerance of 1% or lower.

Comment: LiPo Battery capacity is 500mAh.

Comment: I would use voltage divider but with a PMOS in series at the battery voltage side. Then control the gate from the uC, pull the gate low only during the battery voltage measurement. That way, if you then for example, measure only once every few minutes, power consumption from the voltage divider is so small it can be ignored.

Comment: I could use higher value resistor but how could lower tolerance help (is 5% not sufficient)? and also will this be better in terms of power consumption than that of any alternative for voltage divider?

Comment: BEst practice is to define a list of specs and tolerances.  what you want/ need/ don't want  .. but you need to read a bit more https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+university

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah it's a good idea, I'll try that. But you are suggesting to use PMOS in this case but PMOS will need continuous supply at gate to keep it in OFF state, so it'll take some power continuously. In other case of NMOS we can apply voltage at gate to turn it ON only whenever it is needed to measure power. So will NMOS be not better option or simple NPN Transistor?

Comment: *but PMOS will need continuous supply at gate to keep it in OFF state, so it'll take some power continuously.* **Nope**, a PMOS is a device that takes **no current** into the gate, the gate behaves like a **capacitor**, once (dis)charged, no current flows. Using an NMOS is also possible but you get a "neater" voltage divider if you switch high-side, and that means using a PMOS. I suggest you study how to use MOSFETs.

Comment: When using a PNP as a switch there will always be some voltage drop across it so the battery monitoring will be **less accurate**. A PMOS will drop **significantly less** voltage and acts much more like a real switch. Running out of IO ports: then use a PCF8574 port extender.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for helping.I studied about it and surely will use PMOS in project.But there is one more thing which arose due to this as I was going to indicate with LED whenever the battery is being monitored but as in this case if I connect LED with the same GPIO,the LED will stay ON continuously and will turn OFF when actually it is going to be measured,which I don't want.I wanted the LED to turn ON only when battery voltage is being monitored.Is there any way this can be done same GPIO?As I'm using ESP and no GPIOs are left and don't want to use IO expanders for just one more output.

Comment: Just connect the LED + series resistor in parallel with the voltage divider, then the LED is on when the voltage divider is on. Or connect the LED + resistor between Vbat (battery voltage) and GPIO (instead of between GPIO and ground). Your "issue" really isn't an issue. I suggest you study some other designs using ESP and microcontrollers to learn what is possible. There are plenty of circuit solutions you do not seem to know about.